# VS2013 Office Add-In -- Incompatible with this Version of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, add-in

I wanted to create a Visual Studio 2013 Addin for Excel 2013. So I installed the 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2012/08/17/10340229.aspx Web Plattform Installer as suggested and installed the Office Developer Tools as the Webites tells me to.
This worked fine and I can create now Add-Ins, but as soon as I save and reopen them, I get the message, that the Version of VS is not compatible.
So I think, the installed Templates are just for VS 2012 to simulate 2013.

But where are the real VS2013 Add-Ins for Office 2013? It's a very silly question, probably that's why I can't find anything about it on google, nor on the MSDN-Page etc.

I found a blog for the Office-apps (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2013/06/18/roadmap-for-apps-for-office-vsto-and-vba.aspx), this Templates I would find, but I can't see this being the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here.: http://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforvs2013

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c144a87-917a-4eb1-8716-da61f7efdafc/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-march-2014-update-now-available?forum=lightswitch

There was a new release this month.

edit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I already installed this one. 
Is it correct to create a Office/SharePoint --> Excel 2013 Add-In or would this only work for VS2012?

Comment: Just to be sure: What Template are you selecting, for example for a excel addin?

Comment: Excel 2013 Add-in under visual C#>Office/SharePoint>Office Add-ins

Comment: Installed this stuff new, working now...
No idea, but your Informations helped me a lot.
Thanks!